# ASP.NET app running in PeopleSoft IFrame - problem

Tags: asp.net, peoplesoft

I have a .NET app running inside a Peoplesoft web portal IFrame.
What I need to do is get the URL of the portal (parent) that called my .NET app.
So far I've tried to get the URL inside my c# code using Request.Url.AbsoluteUri but this is not working.

I'm assuming I will have to do this in JavaScript, or is it possible to get the browser's URL inside my c# code?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri on the Start Page of the ASP.NET app did the trick.
All is good now.